# datetime default to right now - parse new Date()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `datetime-local` input in a react component that I would like to default to right now. Using `new Date()` doesn't properly instantiate a value. How do I transform `new Date()` into a format that the `datetime` input accepts?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime) the default `defaultValue` should be `new Date()`, so you shouldn't need to do anything as far as I can tell. The documentation does mention that [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a dependency, it needs to parse dates, have you loaded Moment?

Comment: `Date.now()` --> `1523318648523` or `new Date(1523318773679).toLocaleDateString('en-US')` -> `"4/9/2018"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify method to stringify the datetime

```
var currentDate = JSON.stringify(new Date()).slice(1, 17);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't populate the datetime input field with any value

Comment: try JSON.stringify(), if it still not work. You can manually parse it.